# What do I do after getting the chest and first chocolate bar in Candy Box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

I seem to be stuck. I'm stuck on the candies on the sucker and candy things, after you find the chest and get the first chocolate bar.

I don't know what to do, it's my first time getting this far, I realized their were boots and gloves in the shop, does this have anything to do with me getting stuck?

Comment: What sucker and candy things? could you describe it better or maybe post a picture?

Comment: Explore everywhere you can.  Get yourself a weapon and go forth on an epic journey.

Comment: @Ullallulloo It's right after the little guy gets mad and he digs down and finds a chest, he gets the chocolate bar, he goes into a room with suckers and he walks on them and starts *nom* *nom* I can't describe it.

Comment: @Ullallulloo I figured it out, I just defeated a bunch of rats in a house, I think Im good.

Comment: @Payton - if you've found the answer, you should add it in the answers section below :)

Comment: @Payton You seem to be referring to throwing candies on the ground. As far as I am aware, nothing else happens after the little guy starts eating giant candies.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing candies on the ground is a fun side diversion; the real gameplay is over on the Map tab. It's not just a map of the world, you can actually click on the locations and often find things to do. Explore over there and you'll probably find the plot :)

Answer (score 0):

The boots in the shop are useless but the gloves can be enchanted at the wishing well with a chocolate bar.  The gloves can be enchanted as pink or red.  Red gloves shoot mini fireballs  randomly and pink continually heals you.  I recommended pink but later you will get a unicorn horn that will continually heal you more than the glove.